# ExerciseSelect with counter as key

Tags: counters, exercises

I would like to use `\ExcerciseSelect` to choose some questions in order to create different assignments. I have more than  140 different questions. Ideally I would like to make something like student 1 has questions 1,11,21,...131; student 2 has questions 2,12,22..., 132 and so on. I took a look at some related post, but it seems like using `<counter>` as key is not straightforward. Here is what I do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{myquestion}
Here are some short exercises :

\ExerciseSelect[counter={1}]

\begin{Exercise}[counter={myquestion}] 
  Prove that $1+1=2$. 
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}[counter={myquestion}] 
  Prove that $1+1+1=3$. 
\end{Exercise}


\ExerciseStopSelect

\end{document}
```

I would expect to have only the first question choosen. But it does not. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2):

The `\ExerciseSelect` does not know the `counter` key, but it uses `label={...}` where a comma-separated list of exercise labels can be applied.

This is shown in the example below, see the screen shot as well.

A more sophisticated approach would use `auto-generated` labels according to the exercise counter value.

The `counter` key is valid for the `Exercise(*)` environment only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercise}

\newcounter{myquestion}
\begin{document}

Here are some short exercises :

\ExerciseSelect[label={myquestion3,myquestion1}]

\begin{Exercise}[counter=myquestion,label={myquestion1}] 
  Prove that $1+1=2$. 
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}[counter=myquestion,label={myquestion2}] 
  Prove that $1+1+1=3$. 
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}[counter=myquestion,label={myquestion3}] 
  Prove that $1+1+1+1=4$. 
\end{Exercise}

\ExerciseStopSelect

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try to improve this answer later on, perhaps the `exercise` package can be 'fixed'